# Working around ERROR: Unknown geometry type: 11 - MultiCurve

Tags: postgis, sql

Basically I have a polygon layer and I need to create a view which extracts about 100 different columns from about 10 tables with polygon, line and point geometry, that intersect with the said polygon.

The problem is that after creating the view, when I try to run it, I keep getting this unknown geometry type and it doesn't tell me where the error is located

```
ERROR: Unknown geometry type: 11 - MultiCurve
```

I've tried using `st_isvalid(r.geom) = true` on every single table as a where condition because one of the layers definitely had some invalid geometries, but I keep running into this error.

Comment: It's unclear if your view is pure SQL or being consumed by a GIS app (which is less likely to tolerate different geometry classes in a single view). If your view utilizes a UNION ALL, you can make singleton views to identify the table, and/or just select for `GeometryType(geomcol)` with an ID column.

Comment: thanks a lot Vince! I used the geometrytype(geometry) where geometrytype(geometry) != 'LINESTRING' to search for the multicurves!